# Understanding solr(8.x) default searchHandler

Tags: solr, lucene

This is newbie question, but trying understand solr search handler with defaults enabled.

As per my understanding **df** is used for Default search field, what will happen/how does it work if remove this part?

My scenario currently: I am pushing/adding all fields data (e.g title, department, etc.) to text. So when I search free text it can be searchable (using edismax) and it works as expected. But when tomorrow new fields come, I mean suppose it will be title, department , somefield, then I have to reindex all data again. Then it will be searchable. How can I achieve that? Can I have multiple fields in df?

example : `<str name="df">title, department, etc,etc </str>` like this ?

```xml
<requestHandler name="/select" class="solr.SearchHandler">
<!-- default values for query parameters can be specified, these
     will be overridden by parameters in the request
-->
  <lst name="defaults">
  <str name="echoParams">explicit</str>
  <int name="rows">10</int>
  <!-- Default search field -->
  <str name="df">text</str>
</lst>
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you're using edismax, you can provide the `qf` argument with multiple fields instead - and weights between them. Another option is to have one common field, i.e. something like `text` and a `copyField` instruction that copies everything (source set to `*`) to `text` (`dest` set to `text`), then search against that field.

Using either won't require a reindex, since the content will either be copied from all documents indexed as they're being indexed, or the search will consider more fields (with `qf`).

You can set the default value for the `qf` in the same was a you've shown above in the config file under `defaults`.

Comment: Thanks @MatsLindh so my understanding is correct. Thanks for clarifying doubt. 
so it will be <str name="qf">title, department, etc,etc </str>  or as suggested text/copy field to be used

Comment: Correct. You won't have to reindex after changing the parameter in your configuration.

Comment: @Sthita I don't think it will work - <str name="qf">title, department, etc,etc </str>. It will throw an error "undefined field title, department, etc..". Can you please confirm it?

Comment: @saravanan Why do you believe that `qf` doesn't support multiple field names? Leave a space between them as shown in the reference guide: https://solr.apache.org/guide/6_6/the-dismax-query-parser.html#TheDisMaxQueryParser-Theqf_QueryFields_Parameter - i.e. `qf=title department etc`

Comment: @MatsLindh Sorry it was my misunderstanding. I mentioned about the default fields in solrconfig.xml.